# New computer, slow startup

Tags: windows-10, performance

My newly-built computer starts up really slowly.

Specs:

- CPU: AMD Ryzen 5 3600 6x 3.60GHz
- RAM: Crucial Ballistix Sport DDR4-3200 (In the BIOS the frequency is
  displayed as 2666MHZ)
- MOBO: MSI B450 Tomahawk Max
- STORAGE: Samsung 850 PRO 256GB SSD, 2TB and 1TB HDD
- GPU: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1070

I needed to reinstall Windows (Windows 10 Education). Before I did so the startup time was fine.

The first startup is really slow - about 2 minutes. I don't face this issue when restarting.

The boot sequence is fine, I checked that.

Any help?

Comment: What else you've checked? E.g. Programs opening automatically at startup? Have you tried disabling them?

Comment: It doesn't even show the BIOS symbol. it's just black. So I don't think slow starting programs are the problem.

Comment: Made sure you're running the latest motherboard firmware?

Comment: For the "no BIOS" on startup, it's probably because the Silent Boot option is enabled in BIOS. You would have to press the right key *EXACTLY* at the same time as you press the Power button to enter your BIOS. For the rest, in Windows, go to Power management and disable Fast Startup, then perform a cold boot, not a restart, to see if it's better that way.

Comment: If you can enter your BIOS, well, then, good for you. Have you tried to disable Fast Startup and to perform a cold boot? A note to the admins here: I don't receive notifications when a new comment is posted in a question I have posted a comment to. Notifications used to work, but they don't anymore, at least not for me. Can you guys check what's what?

Comment: @Didier: in case multiple persons are involved in a discussion, only the author of the question /answer will be notified, unless somebody else is explicitly mentioned (https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work) . Next time its better to raise your issue as a question on meta.superuser instead of including it in a comment.

Comment: I thought it was a glitch, that's all. Thanks for the precision.

Comment: @Didier I did, and also installed a firmware update for my BIOS. These methods solved the problem. Thank you very much. =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installing a firmware update for my BIOS and disabling Fast Startup in the power management solved the problem.